# KOL - Load a PStream to an TImage

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, kol

I have a jpeg file saved in a string. I would like to load/assign the string to a TImage in Delphi7. I use [KOL](http://kolmck.net/) for the following Code:

```
var
 ImageStream : PStream;
 ImageString : String;
 MyJpeg      : TJpeg;
begin
 ImageStream:= NewMemoryStream; // Create New Stream.
 ImageStream.Write(ImageString [1], Length(ImageString )); // Fill the stream.
 ImageStream.Position := 0;     // Set Position to 0.
 // ImageStream.SaveToFile('C:\test.jpg', 0, ImageStream.Size); // Debug --> WORKS!
 MyJpeg := TJpegImage.Create; // Create a Jpeg Image. 
 MyJpeg.LoadFromStream(@ImageStream); // ???
 Image1.picture.Assign(MyJpeg);       // No picture is shown
end;
```

It should work since PStream is just a pointer to TStream...
But there is no picture shown in Timage...
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Here we go again... What does "doesn't work" mean? In what way does it "fail here"? You're not giving necessary information with your question. Any time you type "error", "fails", or "doesn't work", the **very next thing** you should type is exactly what you mean, including the **exact** error messages you're receiving with any memory addresses they contain. We can't see your screen from where we are, and can't see the rest of your code either. Please help us to help you. (And, just as a tip, you should reset `ImageStream.Position` *after* the `ImageStream.Write`, not before it.)

Comment: I edited it. Thank you. The problem is that there is no picture shown in Timage.

Comment: You're not reading what I write again. I'll bold it this time: **You should reset `ImageStream.Position` after the `ImageStream.Write`, not before it.**

Comment: I edited the code. There is still no picture shown.

Comment: Benjamin: You did **not** edit the code to move the 'ImageStream.Position :- 0;` **after** the `ImageStream.Write(...);` line. If I say *pretty please* will you actually read what I'm writing this time? :-)

Comment: I did read your comment. I am sorry. I edited the code a while ago. Try CTRL+F5 if the edit doesn't show up yet.

Comment: then there is something wrong with stackoverflow. It says I edited it 1 hour ago... http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/3228/83953468.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You state that

> PStream is just a pointer to TStream

In which case this code

```
MyJpeg.LoadFromStream(@ImageStream);
```

cannot work. You are passing, to a parameter of type `TStream`, a pointer to a pointer to TStream. To make your code compile you need to pass a `TStream` to `LoadFromStream`. Like this:

```
MyJpeg.LoadFromStream(ImageStream^);
```

---

In your position, I would probably use a `TStringStream` like this.

```
var
  Stream: TStringStream;
....
Stream := TStringStream.Create(ImageString);
try
  MyJpeg := TJpegImage.Create;
  try
    MyJpeg.LoadFromStream(Stream);
    Image1.Picture.Assign(MyJpeg);
  finally
    MyJpeg.Free;
  end;
finally
  Stream.Free;
end;
```

Perhaps there is a KOL way to do that, I don't know KOL at all.

Comment: David, we've posted the same answer (seems you posted yours just before I posted mine). Should I delete my answer since it is ostensibly the same?

Comment: @LaKraven No need to delete yours. I just up voted it. In fact yours was before mine by a few seconds. I might delete mine if yours wins because I'm already at rep cap today.

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss After you accepted the answer, I added some commentary on your use of `PStream = ^TStream`. Does this hit the mark or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you aren't freeing `Stream` or `MyJpeg` when you're done using them. Memory leaks would be produced.

Comment: @LaKraven I know. I was just assuming that those details were being omitted so that we could concentrate on the main points. I've edited it to stop leaking.

Comment: Fair enough. Based on the code example Benjamin provided, I assume he isn't freeing his objects, thus why I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: @David, the `NewMemoryStream` function is from [`KOL`](http://kolmck.net/e_kolmck.htm) where the streams are instantiated in a different way.

Comment: @TLama Thanks. My curiosity is piqued now. I will take a look at KOL.

Answer (score 7):

You're passing a Pointer to a Pointer to a TStream descendant. You need to dereference your `ImageStream` variable when you call `LoadFromStream`. See code sample below:

```
var
 ImageStream : PStream;
 ImageString : String;
 MyJpeg      : TJpeg;
begin
 ImageStream:= NewMemoryStream; // Create New Stream.
 ImageStream.Write(ImageString [1], Length(ImageString )); // Fill the stream.
 ImageStream.Position := 0;     // Set Position to 0.
 // ImageStream.SaveToFile('C:\test.jpg', 0, ImageStream.Size); // Debug --> WORKS!
 MyJpeg := TJpegImage.Create; // Create a Jpeg Image. 
 MyJpeg.LoadFromStream(ImageStream^); // Dereference PStream to TStream
 Image1.picture.Assign(MyJpeg);       // Your picture is now shown
end;
```

If your `NewMemoryStream` method is returning a `PStream`, you should really determine *whether that's necessary*, and try to make it return `TStream` instead. There's no advantage to using `PStream` over `TStream` in the context of the code you've presented.

Also, you're not freeing your `ImageStream` object!

Use this instead:

```
var
  ImageStream: TStream;
  ImageString: String;
begin
  ImageStream := NewMemoryStream;
  try
    ImageStream := NewMemoryStream;
    ImageStream.Write(ImageString[1], Length(ImageString));
    ImageStream.Position := 0;

    Image1.Picture.LoadFromStream(ImageStream);
  finally
    ImageStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I don't know why you're creating a `TJpegImage` instance at all. Your original code introduces two memory leaks every time it's called. My revised version above cleans up after itself properly.

Comment: Timage doens't know which picture it is. It has to be assigned first to a jpeg or bitmap. There is not even Picture.LoadFromStream... only Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromStream

Comment: It may just be a Delphi 7 thing. When I do `Image1.Picture.LoadFromStream(SomeStream);` where `SomeStream` contains a JPEG image, the image is loaded correctly. This has been the case for me from Delphi 2009 and up. Not used Delphi 7 in years, so cannot remember if it should work the same for you or not.